# Using R.Framework in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, r

I'm just starting out with trying to bring in R.Framework into a Objective-C project.  I'm running into an issue with a fatal error:

```
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Headers/R_ext/Boolean.h:31:16: Redefinition of enumerator 'FALSE'
```

Here's what I have in my main.m file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <R.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    @autoreleasepool {

        Rprintf("testing R");

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I suspect it's how I'm including the R.h.  I've tried `#import` as well, but I got the same issue.

**EDIT:**

In addition, Xcode is letting me know that the original definition is being made in the `usr/include/mach-o/dyld.h` file.

Also, I downloaded the open source Mac App for R (Mac-GUI-1.65.tar.gz) from [here](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/) and successfully built it on the same machine.

**EDIT 2:**

The compiler is saying that the following, within `usr/include/mach-o/dyld.h`, is the previous definition:

```
#ifndef ENUM_DYLD_BOOL
#define ENUM_DYLD_BOOL
  #undef FALSE
  #undef TRUE
  enum DYLD_BOOL { FALSE, TRUE };
#endif /* ENUM_DYLD_BOOL */
```

The conflict is that in one of the header files (Boolean.h) in the R.Framework has this:

```
typedef enum { FALSE = 0, TRUE /*, MAYBE */ } Rboolean;
```

And anytime I include `R.h`, it throws this error saying there is a Redefinition of the enumerator 'FALSE' and 'TRUE'.

Answer (score 1):

Both `Foundation.h` and `R.h` define `TRUE` and `FALSE`. To work around this, you'll need to `#undef` these symbols before including the other, e.g.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#undef TRUE
#undef FALSE
#include <R.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    @autoreleasepool {

        Rprintf("testing R");

    }
    return 0;
}
```

You may need to play around with include order / `#undef` and re-defining symbols to get things to work right.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried a few different ordering approaches, I'm still getting the same issue.  

FYI: Xcode is letting me know that the original definition is being made in the usr/include/mach-o/dyld.h file.

Comment: That is useful information, would you mind adding it to the question?

Comment: If this doesn't work, I can't think of a better solution barring modifying the R headers directly :(